# GCC 7.1 won't fully optimize rotate, if rotation parameter is unsigned char. Is this reasonable?

Tags: gcc

[gcc flags: -O3 -funsigned-char] [ [asm explorer](https://godbolt.org)  ]

```
//partially optimized to: and, rol
unsigned int rol(unsigned int x, unsigned char r) 
{
   r &= 31; return (x << r) | (x >> (32-r));
}

//optimized to single: rol
unsigned int rol(unsigned int x, unsigned int r) 
{
   r &= 31; return (x << r) | (x >> (32-r));
}
```

Comment: Your godbolt link is broken. What do you mean "is it reasonable?"? Please show the generated asm and what you would expect in your question.

Comment: Note that for `r==0` your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: According to c standard x >> 32, is undefined, gcc issues a warning but, the resulting expression evaluates to either " x | 0 " , " x | x " and both are equal to "x" , so the end result is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compile with `-da` and look at the generated `*.combine`dump, you can see that the second function successfully matches

```
    (set (reg:SI 91)
        (rotate:SI (reg/v:SI 89 [ x ])
            (subreg:QI (and:SI (reg/v:SI 90 [ r ])
                    (const_int 31 [0x1f])) 0)))
```

while the first one fails on

```
    (set (reg:SI 93)
        (rotate:SI (reg/v:SI 90 [ x ])
            (and:QI (subreg:QI (reg:SI 92 [ r ]) 0)
                (const_int 31 [0x1f]))))
```

The order of going from int to char and performing the `and` is different. Gcc is probably missing a transformation that canonicalizes one to the other, or in the worst case a second pattern.

Please report to [GCC's bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) if you cannot find a similar report already there.